# How to install a JS code for rollovers

Tags: javascript, rollover, installation

I googled rollover code and found one that seems like it ought to work at this address: http://www.dnolan.com/code/js/rollover/.  It probably works and everything but...heh heh...I don't know how to "create a rollover state for any image in my document".  The way Mr. Nolan gives the instruction implies that it is even more simple than installing the code in the document header and therefore needs no explanation, but sadly, such is not the case in my...case.

I need it for my navbar, which consists of a row of 8 circular images, to be replaced upon hovering with images of the same size and shape, but of a different color.

Could any of you brilliant people fill in the missing information?  I just need the part that has no corresponding example—I've got the part in the tag and in the header, and I made the appropriate changes to the names of the images.  Or if you could be a REAL peach and give me a step by step for the whole thing, I would be eternally grateful.

```
  <div id="header">
    <div id="home"><a href="feather.html"><img src="images/buttons/home.png" width="89"     height="89" alt="Home"></a></div>
    <div id="security"><a href="security.html"><img src="images/buttons/security_o.png" width="89" height="89" alt="Security"></a></div>
    <div id="phase_1"><a href="phase_1.html"><img src="images/buttons/phase_1.png" width="89" height="89" alt="Phase 1"></a></div>
    <div id="phase_2"><a href="phase_2.html"><img src="images/buttons/phase_2.png" width="89" height="89" alt="Phase 2"></a></div>
    <div id="phase_3"><a href="phase_3.html"><img src="images/buttons/phase_3.png" width="89" height="89" alt="Phase 3"></a></div>
    <div id="basic_package"><a href="basic_package.html"><img src="images/buttons/basic_package.png" width="89" height="89" alt="Basic Package"></a></div>

#header  {
background-image: url(images/complete_header.jpg);
background-repeat: no-repeat;
height: 391px;
width: 900px;
position: relative;
}

#home  {
width: 89px;
height: 89px;
position: absolute;
top: 199px;
left: 91px;
}
```

The CSS for the other 7 buttons is exactly the same except for the left positioning.

Comment: Please post a code example of the CSS+HTML for one of the nav items in your question.

Comment: I added the code.  Let me know if you need anything else.  Anything I can do to help you help me.

Answer (score 2):

Just read your link a little futher:

> for any image in your document you will need to create a rollover state for it, the only requirements for this image is that it is named exactly the same as the original image, but it needs _o on the end of the name.

So if you have an image `foo.jpg`, it expects you to have a `foo_o.jpg` to replace it with in a rollover.

Of course, this is much better done with css and using sprites. A Google search should bring up lots of results for that. Here's the [first example](http://www.elated.com/articles/css-rollover-buttons/) that came up for me.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should just add a class of `imgover` to every image you want to use rollover.

For example replace `<img src="sample.jpg" alt="Some Image">` in your code by `<img src="sample.jpg" alt="Some Image" class="imgover">` and create a sample_o.jpg image